# Fetch text from unnamed QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qgraphicstextitem

A friend of mine and I are currently trying to make a game in C++ using Qt. Our current problem is that we need to fetch text from a `QGraphicsTextItem` on a button `mousePressEvent`. In the game menu it is possible to choose how many players there are, therefore we've placed a `QGraphicsTextItem` in a for-loop to make it possible for all the users to type in their names. Because of the for-loop, we don't have names for every single text item object so we can store the names. We've managed to store all the memory addresses to the objects using `QMap`, but we don't know how to get the text of of this. We don't even know if this is the best way to do it.

> GameInfo.h

```
class GameInfo {
public:
    GameInfo();
    int players;

    QStringList names = (QStringList() // Default player names. This array should be overwritten by the custom names
        << "Player 1"
        << "Player 2"
        << "Player 3"
        << "Player 4"
        << "Player 5"
        << "Player 6"
        << "Player 7");

    QMap<int, QGraphicsTextItem**> textBoxMap; // This is where we store all the addresses
};
```

> Game.cpp

```
    QGraphicsRectItem * overviewBox = new QGraphicsRectItem();
    overviewBox->setRect(0, 0, 782, 686);
    scene->addItem(overviewBox);

    int faceNo = 0;

// Create the player selection section
    for(int i = 1; i <= players; i++) { // "players" is defined another place in the code, and is an integer between 1 and 6
        Container * selContainer = new Container();
        selContainer->Selection(i, faceNo);
        selContainer->setPos(50, 70 + 110 * (i - 1));
        scene->addItem(selContainer);
        Container * ovContainer = new Container(overviewBox);
        ovContainer->Overview(i, faceNo);
        ovContainer->setPos(0, 0 + 110 * (i - 1));

        info->textBoxMap.insert(i, &selContainer->textBox->playerText); // This is where we save the addresses
    }
```

> Selection.cpp

```
extern Game * game;

Container::Container(QGraphicsItem * parent): QGraphicsRectItem(parent) {

}

void Container::Selection(int nPlayers, int sPiceNo, QGraphicsItem *parent) {

    QString numName = QString::number(nPlayers);

    setRect(0, 0, 672, 110);
    this->setPen(Qt::NoPen); // Removes border

    int posY = this->rect().height() / 2;

    QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    arrowL = new Arrow(0, posY - 32, 0, this);
    piece = new Piece(sPiceNo, 96, posY - 32, 1, 1, this);
    arrowR = new Arrow(192, posY - 32, 1, this);
    textBox = new TextBox(game->info->names[nPlayers - 1], true, this);
    textBox->setPos(288, posY - 32);
    lockBtn = new Button("Lock", 96, 32, this);
    connect(lockBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(lockBtn, nPlayers);
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(lock(int)));
    lockBtn->setPos(640, posY - 16);

}


void Container::Overview(int ovPlayers, int ovPiceNo, QGraphicsItem * parent) {
    // Some code...
}

void Container::lock(int nPlayer) {
    qDebug() << game->info->textBoxMap[nPlayer];
    qDebug() << game->info->names[nPlayer - 1];

    game->info->names[nPlayer - 1] = **game->info->textBoxMap[nPlayer].toPlainText(); // This line causes an error
}
```

The error that occurs because of the last line looks like this:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QString' and 'QGraphicsTextItem')
 game->info->names[nPlayer - 1] = **game->info->textBoxMap[nPlayer];
                                ^
```

> TextBox.cpp

```
TextBox::TextBox(QString text, bool editable, QGraphicsItem * parent): QGraphicsRectItem(parent) {
    this->editable = editable;

// Draw the textbox
    setRect(0, 0, 320, 64);
    if(!editable) {
        this->setPen(Qt::NoPen); // Removes border
    }
    else if(editable) {
        QBrush brush;
        brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
        brush.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 255));
        setBrush(brush);
    }

// Draw the text
    playerText = new QGraphicsTextItem(text, this);
    int fontId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/built_titling_bd.ttf");

    QString family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(fontId).at(0);
    QFont built(family, 25);
    playerText->setFont(built);
    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = rect().height() / 2 - playerText->boundingRect().height() / 2;
    playerText->setPos(xPos,yPos);
}
```

My question is how do i fetch the text from the `QGraphicsTextItem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to learn a bit more about C++ before trying to develop a game imo. (Having public variables is against OO's and C++ paradigm)

But here is what you are looking for:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html#toPlainText

EDIT:

If you are not able to debug some line of code, I could only recommend to try to seperate your code in order to have a minimum of call in a single line. I haven't try the code bellow, but that how you should try to debug your code:

```
    void Container::lock(int nPlayer)
    {
       qDebug() << game->info->textBoxMap[nPlayer];
       qDebug() << game->info->names[nPlayer - 1];
       QGraphicsTextItem **value = game->info->textBoxMap.value(nPlayer, nullptr);
       game->info->names[nPlayer - 1] =(*value)->toPlainText();
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I burned your eyes, that was not the purpose of this post. Anyways, I've tried your suggestion about the toPlainText(), but it didn't work either.

Comment: That's OK, I've edit my first version of the post, a bit too rude maybe ;).
Could you explain how that didn't work please?

Comment: I don't think it was rude, just fun :) When I tried the toPlainText() I got this error: request for member 'toPlainText' in '* game->Game::info->GameInfo::textBoxMap.QMap<Key, T>::operator[]<int, QGraphicsTextItem**>((*(const int*)(& nPlayer)))', which is of pointer type 'QGraphicsTextItem*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)      game->info->names[nPlayer - 1] = **game->info->textBoxMap[nPlayer]->toPlainText();

Comment: Read the error again. The answer lie within.



pssssst. "maybe you meant to use '->' ?"

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. I do use the '->' before toPlainText()

Comment: game->info->names[nPlayer - 1] = **game->info->textBoxMap[nPlayer]->toPlainText();

Comment: I have updated my answer, please tick as answered if it's what you were trying to do.